# No Man's Sky and Steam Family Library...can we play at the same time?

Tags: steam, no-mans-sky, steam-family-sharing

My husband bought me No Man's Sky (NMS) for xmas.  He saw how much I was enjoying it, and started playing it himself via the Steam Family Library (we share with each other).

Every other game we have, if one of us (person A) is playing a game from the other's library, and the person whose game it is (person B) starts playing another game, Person A will get a Steam pop-up notice that Person B is playing another game from their own library, and that Person A has 5 minutes before their game will be closed automatically.  Additionally, if Person A is playing a game from their own library, Person B is not able to start playing a game from Person A's library until Person A quits the game they're playing.

However, with NMS, I am able to play any game from my library (all of which are shared with him) without Steam booting him from No Man's Sky.  He can also start playing No Man's Sky (which is in my library) while I am playing another game from my library.  Finally, I am able to start playing any of his games while he is playing NMS, which also normally wouldn't work (at least for us).

So this got me wondering...does anyone know if we can both play NMS at the same time, even though only one of us (me) actually *owns* a copy?  Does the fact that he bought the game through his Steam account and gifted it to me have anything to do with it?

Comment: Interesting. This sounds like a bug, as I can't imagine this being a feature. As an answer to the question: you tell us, can you play NMS simultaneously? :)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Turns out it's a moot point now - husband decided to buy his own copy of the game lol. (Still curious though.)

Comment: I don't think this should have been marked as duplicate, as not all games will support that steam feature.